# How to texture a huge city?

Tags: texturing, uv

I followed a tutorial to create a city using .osm map file, and ended up with a red-colored city, (with red buildings), I wanted to know how do I texture it?
[Tutorial I followed](http://www.creativeshrimp.com/how-to-create-a-city-covered-with-fog.html)
[image]
In the tutorial, he states something about a texture atlas, which I couldnt understand. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around 2:00 minutes at the step 4 of the video tutorial : compose the texture atlas.
This texture is simply a single large image composed of several buildings facades and roofs images found on CGTextures.com.
So this is simply a copy/paste process.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, after composing the atlas, how to i texture the buildings?

Comment: I am not able to explain it here better than it is in the video itself... What is your specific question about it ?

Comment: I dont know how to apply the texture facades from the image onto the buildings

Comment: @AineshSootha, this video is surely made for people with some Blender experience. But you can learn more for instance here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2-FfB9kRmE. But many other tutorials are available. Search for "blender UV unwrapping" : https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=blender+uv+unwrap&tbm=vid

Comment: *texure atlas* is also the name of an addon (included in blender) that helps you combine the textures of many objects into one like @lemon said in his answer:)